# Redirect filtered output to file

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, pipe

I redirect my output into a file and I get something like this:

```
|  id  | code | color_code | 
-------+------+------------+
|11A00B|  15  | 9129102    |
|11A00C|  16  | 9129103    |
(2 rows)

|  id  | code | color_code | 
-------+------+------------+
|11B00B|  25  | 9129152    |
|11B00C|  36  | 9129162    |
(2 rows)

|  id  | code | color_code | 
-------+------+------------+
|11C00B|  22  | 9129107    |
|11C00C|  9   | 9129108    |
(2 rows)
```

How can I convert it into csv style like:

```
|  id  | code | color_code | 
|11A00B|  15  | 9129102    |
|11A00C|  16  | 9129103    |
|11B00B|  25  | 9129152    |
|11B00C|  36  | 9129162    |
|11C00B|  22  | 9129107    |
|11C00C|  9   | 9129108    |
```

To get the first file the loop runs and starts sql scripts. All I do is simply `> file`. But I have no control over the loop. Probably info can already be filtered during the iteration. But this is rather doubtful.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Could you mark your preferred answer as accepted? http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

`awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1; /^\|[0-9]/'
```

- The default action in `awk` is to print the record
- `NR==1` matches the first record (line)
- `/^\|[0-9]/` matches any record starting with `|` followed by a digit

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                    
|  id  | code | color_code | 
-------+------+------------+
|11A00B|  15  | 9129102    |
|11A00C|  16  | 9129103    |
(2 rows)

|  id  | code | color_code | 
-------+------+------------+
|11B00B|  25  | 9129152    |
|11B00C|  36  | 9129162    |
(2 rows)

|  id  | code | color_code | 
-------+------+------------+
|11C00B|  22  | 9129107    |
|11C00C|  9   | 9129108    |
(2 rows)

% awk 'NR==1; /^\|[0-9]/' file.txt
|  id  | code | color_code | 
|11A00B|  15  | 9129102    |
|11A00C|  16  | 9129103    |
|11B00B|  25  | 9129152    |
|11B00C|  36  | 9129162    |
|11C00B|  22  | 9129107    |
|11C00C|  9   | 9129108    |
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pipe your output through this `sed` command:

```
sed '1p;/^|/!d;/^|\s*id/d'
```

Explanation:

- The expression `1p` just echoes the first line.
- The expression `/^|/!d` removes any line not beginning with `|`.
- The expression `/^|\s*id/d` removes any line beginning with `|`, then some (or none) whitespace characters followed by `id`. We have already printed our header using the first expression, so it is OK that this expression discards it now.

Comment: On the last expression, could it be `/^|\s+id/d` ti accomodate different-sized headers?

Comment: @Kroltan Almost, you would need `sed -r` to support `+`, or use `*` instead of `+`.

Comment: @Kroltan You’ll also need to escape all the `|`’s when using `sed -r`.

Comment: you can get `+` without `-r` if you escape it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` to print only the stuff you want

```
sed -n '1p; /^|[0-9]/p' file
```

#### Explanation

`-n` don't print anything until we ask for it
`1p` print the first line
`^|[0-9]/p` print the line if it starts with `|` followed by a number

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little perl script you can use for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my$file="file.txt";

open(IN,"<",$file); 
my$head=<IN>; 
print $head; 
while(<IN>)
{
  print $_ if $_=~/^\|\S+/;
} 
close IN;
```

This will print the first line of your input file as header and then loop over the rest of the file and print the content lines.

**Note:**

I am assuming here that your content rows always start with a pipe symbol, followed by one ore more non-whitespace characters (`|\S+`). Please leave me a comment if that is not the case, then I can adjust the regex.

Comment: if you are going to use perl then you might as well use its DBI module to connect to the database, its really easy and gives you total control over the output

Answer (score 1):

```
your_command | grep "|"
```

will get rid of those (2 rows) and empty line.
You can add another grep -v "id" which will remove all headers, then you just need to add one header with echo command to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

How about this little shell-script? It uses user596137's answer with `grep` and writes the output in that file

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
FIRST_LINE=`head -n1 ${FILE}`
INPUT=`cat ${FILE} | grep "|" | grep -v "id"`

echo "$FIRST_LINE" > $FILE; echo "$INPUT" >> $FILE
```

Save that script and grant execution permission to it. This script needs a file name as the first parameter.